# Gradle custom task which runs multiple tasks

Tags: gradle

I wanna run multiple gradle tasks as one. So instead of

```
./gradlew clean build publish
```

I want to have a custom task

```
./gradlew cleanBuildPublish
```

that executes `clean` `build` and `publish` in order.

How's that possible?

This does not work

```
task cleanBuildPublish {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    dependsOn 'build'
    dependsOn 'publish'
}
```

Comment: Are you using java plugin?

Comment: @SantoshGokak yes I do

Answer (score 163, accepted):

If you need to execute some tasks in predefined order, then you need to not only set `dependsOn`, but also to set `mustRunAfter` property for this tasks, like in the following code:

```
task cleanBuildPublish {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    dependsOn 'build'
    dependsOn 'publish'
    tasks.findByName('build').mustRunAfter 'clean'
    tasks.findByName('publish').mustRunAfter 'build'
}
```

`dependsOn` doesn't define an order of tasks execution, it just make one task dependent from another, while `mustRunAfter` does.

Comment: Would it with that still be possible to execute the tasks solely?

Comment: Why not. You set all this dependencies only while execute the task

Comment: I get this error `Cannot invoke method mustRunAfter() on null object`

Comment: seems, gradle didn't find task with name build or publish, check wether they are in the same project, if not, you have to specify this names with project they belong to.

Comment: one more, your cleanBuildPublish task must be placed after all 3 dependent tasks in your build script

Comment: i had same issue as Niklas. build should be implicit. we don't define that task in gradle. this is for java project

Comment: Make sure to put the `cleanBuildPublish` after all the individual tasks have been defined. Seems gradle tasks are read from top to bottom. That resolved my issue for `Cannot invoke method mustRunAfter() on null object `

Comment: It is important to mention gradle does not wait for the task to finish

Comment: Why does Gradle make it so awkward to do a simple and common operation like this? Are there plans to improve this?

Comment: Isn't it wonderful how Gradle syntax keeps changing? now it'd be: `task cleanBuildPublish(dependOn: [clean, build, publish])` then `build.mustRunAfter clean` etc. AFAICS

Comment: at least it's not Maven

Answer (score 120):

You can also use the task base class called [`GradleBuild`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild.html)

Here how you can do that with `GradleBuild`

**Groovy DSL:**

```
task cleanBuildPublish(type: GradleBuild) {
     tasks = ['clean', 'build', 'publish']
}
```

**Kotlin DSL:**

```
tasks.register<GradleBuild>("cleanBuildPublish") {
    tasks = listOf("clean", "build", "publish")
}
```

Comment: so task will be executed in sequence mentioned?

Comment: kotlin version of it?

Comment: Kotlin Version would be very similar. You just want to use `project.tasks.register` to create your task and that's all.

Comment: The Gradle project specifically recommends against doing this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/authoring_maintainable_build_scripts.html#sec:avoiding_use_of_gradlebuild

Comment: Beware of nested calls: When running `gradlew cleanBuildPublish somethingElse`, then `somethingElse` could be run first

Answer (score 6):

My approach is

```
task cleanBuildPublish (type: GradleBuild, dependsOn: ['clean', 'build', 'publish']) { 
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: The Gradle project specifically recommends against doing this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/authoring_maintainable_build_scripts.html#sec:avoiding_use_of_gradlebuild

Comment: @Alex OK - any idea how to do it though?

Answer (score 5):

Try below way to make cleanBuildPublish depend on other tasks

build.gradle

```
task clean{
    println "lets clean"
}

task build {
    println "lets build"
}

task publish {
    println "lets publish"
}

task cleanBuildPublish{
    println 'lets do all'
}


cleanBuildPublish.dependsOn clean
cleanBuildPublish.dependsOn build
cleanBuildPublish.dependsOn publish
```

Output

```
$ gradle cleanBuildPublish
lets clean
lets build
lets publish
lets do all
:build UP-TO-DATE
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:publish UP-TO-DATE
:cleanBuildPublish UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.738 secs
```

check https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#addDependencyUsingTask for more details

Comment: Still does not. Output: http://pastebin.com/8knNfLEY Gradle task http://pastebin.com/NaHhdRkA

Comment: Kindly share your build.gradle file

Comment: Project: http://pastebin.com/4uN9Usvd Calendar module: http://pastebin.com/CPzYKNqx Publishing.gradle http://pastebin.com/XMMQUG4C

Comment: The order is not guaranteed. You also need `mustRunAfter`

Answer (score 4):

If publish task is in a sub project named subProjectName,

```
...
tasks.findByPath(':subProjectName:publish').mustRunAfter 'build'
...
```

Answer (score 2):

A generic way to get it, would be the following:

```
task cleanBuildPublish {
  def containedTasks = [clean, build, publish]
  dependsOn containedTasks
  placeTasksInOrder(containedTasks)
}

def placeTasksInOrder(List tasks) {
  for (int i=0; i < tasks.size() -1; i++) {
    def earlierTask = tasks.get(i)
    def laterTask   = tasks.get(i +1)
    laterTask.mustRunAfter(earlierTask)
  }
}
```

`dependsOn` causes the other tasks to run when `cleanBuildPublish` is run and the helper function `placeTasksInOrder` place the tasks in order by calling `mustRunAfter`

When executing `gradlew cleanBuildPublish somethingElse` the order will be `clean, build, publish, somethingElse`

---

*Beware*:
The following solution does **NOT** work if you have nested gradle calls

```
task cleanBuildPublish(type: GradleBuild) {
     tasks = ['clean', 'build', 'publish']
}
```

When executing `gradlew cleanBuildPublish somethingElse`, then it could happen, that `somethingElse`will be called first.
So one should better use the `mustRunAfter`configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about `mustRunAfter`. I have a question. Is there a way I can put a log entry just to know which task is executing? For example "Cleaning..." and then "Done Cleaning". I mean log entries in between calls

Comment: `gradlew ... --info` shows you which tasks are executed. If you want to put custom log entries in your scripts, use `println "My Text"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, with Kotlin scripting, using both dependsOn and mustRunAfter. Here is an example of running two tasks, one (custom registered "importUnicodeFiles" task) that is in "this" project and one (predefined "run" task) that is in a sibling project named ":unicode":

```
tasks.register("rebuildUnicodeFiles") {
    description = "Force the rebuild of the `./src/main/resources/text` data"
    val make = project(":unicode").tasks["run"]
    val copy = tasks["importUnicodeFiles"]
    dependsOn(make)
    dependsOn(copy)
    copy.mustRunAfter(make)
}
```

The Gradle developers generally advise against this approach (they say that forcing ordering is bad, and that executing tasks from other projects is bad), and are working on a way to publish results between projects; see: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows and it works for me.

```
task cleanBuildPublish {

    task _clean {
        dependsOn 'clean'
    }

    task _build {
        dependsOn '_clean'
        dependsOn 'build'
    }

    dependsOn '_build'
    dependsOn 'publish'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to use the pattern separated by a comma

```
check.dependsOn jacocoTestReport, jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

Answer (score -3):

Try adding `defaultTasks` in build.gradle. For eg.
`defaultTasks 'clean', 'build', 'publish'`