# how to sync gradle with terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Android studio sync build.gradle is so slow,
this is a part of log:

```
:app:incrementalApkFlavorReleaseUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:preApkFlavorReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareApkFlavorReleaseUnitTestDependencies
:app:compileApkFlavorReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:processApkFlavorReleaseUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileApkFlavorReleaseUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleApkFlavorReleaseUnitTest
:app:testApkFlavorReleaseUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalPluginFlavorDebugUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:prePluginFlavorDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePluginFlavorDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:compilePluginFlavorDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:processPluginFlavorDebugUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compilePluginFlavorDebugUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:assemblePluginFlavorDebugUnitTest
:app:testPluginFlavorDebugUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalPluginFlavorReleaseUnitTestJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:prePluginFlavorReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePluginFlavorReleaseUnitTestDependencies
:app:compilePluginFlavorReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:processPluginFlavorReleaseUnitTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compilePluginFlavorReleaseUnitTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:assemblePluginFlavorReleaseUnitTest
:app:testPluginFlavorReleaseUnitTest UP-TO-DATE
:app:test UP-TO-DATE
:app:check
:app:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

it will build all flavor ,do check , etc..  I was very hurt, you never know how hard one gay from China want to build a project.  the slow DNS, the netwok limit.. Pzzzz.. my heart..oh..

So, what can i do with terminal , is there a task do sync ?  I don't want do any  redundant task.
By the way , can I see the source code of android studio sync ? can i configure it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With command line in your root project

./gradlew build

It will sync and build your app

To see all available gradle task, use ./gradlew tasks

Comment: build is the slowest task , it almost do every task...  can I do a simple task to sync it ?

Comment: running this cmd in android folder worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

You can do `gradle eclipse cleanEclipse`. It sets up the project for eclipse and downloads all dependencies. Then `cleanEclipse` to remove the eclipse files.

I haven't tested, but I think this should allow `gradle sync` to run those two tasks. Adapted from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907275/gradle-custom-task-which-runs-multiple-tasks)

```
task sync(type: GradleBuild) {
     tasks = ['eclipse', 'cleanEclipse']
}
```