# Task with name not found by using tasks.getByName

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to create tasks with order of tasks

```
task fabricUploadDebug(type: Exec) {
dependsOn 'clean'
dependsOn 'compileDebugSources'
dependsOn 'assembleDebug'
dependsOn 'installDebug'
dependsOn 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug'
tasks.getByName('compileDebugSources').mustRunAfter('clean')
tasks.getByName('assembleDebug').mustRunAfter('compileDebugSources')
tasks.getByName('installDebug').mustRunAfter('assembleDebug')
tasks.getByName('crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug').mustRunAfter('installDebug')}
```

I'm trying to run the task from right panel "Gradle", But error is

```
Gradle sync failed: Task with name 'compileDebugSources' not found in project ':app'. // // Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (2s 87ms) (moments ago)
```

Here is about 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32909428/2425851

**UPDATE**
I tried to output all tasks what I have:

```
 for(item in tasks){
        println "group= "+item.group+" ,path= "+item.path
    }
```

But I have only this: **Why I haven't access to other tasks?**

```
group= build ,path= :app:assemble
group= build ,path= :app:assembleAndroidTest
group= build ,path= :app:buildDependents
group= build ,path= :app:buildNeeded
group= verification ,path= :app:check
group= build ,path= :app:cleanBuildCache
group= null ,path= :app:compileLint
group= verification ,path= :app:connectedCheck
group= null ,path= :app:consumeConfigAttr
group= verification ,path= :app:deviceCheck
group= null ,path= :app:extractProguardFiles
group= null ,path= :app:fabricUploadDebug
group= null ,path= :app:lint
group= null ,path= :app:preBuild
group= null ,path= :app:resolveConfigAttr
group= Android ,path= :app:sourceSets
group= Install ,path= :app:uninstallAll
```

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to black out the project name on the gradle sync panel ;). Joking aside you can use `gradle tasks` to see the list of available tasks. Finally, why do you need this specific task if you are bound to `assembleDebug`?

Comment: @Antoine I want to clean project, then build apk, then install it to device, and then upload the build to fabric

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you :

```
task fabricUploadDebug(type: Exec), dependsOn : ['clean',
                                                 'compileDebugSources',
                                                 'assembleDebug',
                                                 'installDebug',
                                                 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug'] {

    compileDebugSources.dependsOn clean
    assembleDebug.dependsOn compileDebugSources
    installDebug.dependsOn assembleDebug
    crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug.dependsOn installDebug
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all gradle will dynamically generate tasks for android with the different build variants (most likely *debug* and *release*).
So to see all the generated tasks you can use the command `gradle tasks`, or `gradle :app:tasks` to see the tasks available only for your application.

Secondly, it seems that the `CrashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug` task only depends on `assembleDebug` (as you can see on [the documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html#distribution-with-gradle)) so the call to `CompileDebugSources` doesn't seems to be necessary.

Finally, it seems that you want to create a [GradleBuild task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.GradleBuild.html), you can define it as follow:

```
task fabricUploadDebug(type: GradleBuild) {
  tasks = ['clean', 'assembleDebug', 'installDebug', 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug']
}
```