# gradle build only on specified subprojects

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I have a Gradle Java project with 4 modules, and in my CI/CD flow I clean and build the project with `./gradlew clean build` which runs these tasks on all 4 modules. But I actually need them to be run only on 3 of them.
So the question is, how can I create a task, which will clean and build only the modules I need?

I got up to this point:

```
allprojects.findAll { it.name in ['module1', 'module2', 'module3'] }. each { p ->
    configure(p) {
        println p.name
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to go further and even if I am in right direction or not..

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
allprojects.findAll { it.name in ['module1', 'module2', 'module3'] }. each { p ->
    configure(p) {
        task customTask {
            dependsOn 'clean'
            dependsOn 'build'
            tasks.findByName('build').mustRunAfter 'clean'
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `dependsOn` you may be interested in [GradleBuild](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/GradleBuild.html). I failed to configure it properly, that is why I've used `dependsOn`.

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907275/gradle-custom-task-which-runs-multiple-tasks)