# Create a Gradle task with multiple sub-tasks in a specific order

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle command and I am trying to create a custom task so that it is easier to execute each time.

Here is a sample of how my gradle command looks

```
./gradlew build checkStats :project:module:verify :project:module:createJar :project:module:createOApi :project:module:setupConfigs :deploy
```

I tried following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907275/gradle-custom-task-which-runs-multiple-tasks), but I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to run my task.

```
> Could not create task ':myNewTask'.
   > Cannot invoke method mustRunAfter() on null object
```

This is how I can setup `myNewTask` in my `.gradle` file. What am I missing here? Can I directly reference to a task using the `:project:module:task` pattern?

```
tasks.register('myNewTask') {
    dependsOn 'build'
    dependsOn 'checkStats'
    dependsOn ':project:module:verify'
    dependsOn ':project:module:createJar'
    dependsOn ':project:module:createOApi'
    dependsOn ':project:module:setupConfigs'
    dependsOn ':deploy'

    tasks.findByName('checkStats').mustRunAfter('build')
    tasks.findByName(':project:module:verify').mustRunAfter('checkStats')    
    tasks.findByName(':project:module:createJar').mustRunAfter(':project:module:verify')    
    tasks.findByName(':project:module:createOApi').mustRunAfter(':project:module:createJar')    
    tasks.findByName(':project:module:setupConfigs').mustRunAfter(':project:module:createOApi')    
    tasks.findByName('deploy').mustRunAfter(':project:module:setupConfigs')    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on the task names alone, it appears most of these tasks produce some sort of output. If that's the case, then it would be better/idiomatic to express the task dependencies in terms of task outputs/inputs. For example, `myNewTask` depends on the JAR output of `:project:module:createJar` therefore should declare that as input to `myNewTask`. Expressing your task dependencies in this manner allows Gradle to determine whether a task should run or not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on those it can be specified?